# The “history” link under nominations on election pages is dislocated and larger than the others

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, hyperlinks, election

Under nominations on election pages, there are three links: *link, history,* and *flag.* For some reason the *history* link is shown in a slightly larger font and also a bit higher than the others:

[image: illustrating the problem]

I observe this for the ongoing elections on [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/election) and [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election), so it does not appear to be related to site-specific design. However, I don’t see this for older elections, where the *flag* button is missing.

Comment: I can reproduce this on a Samsung running Windows 10 Home and Chrome, though I don't have an account on either site so the "flag" link isn't there.

Comment: Related: ["History" button is not aligned with the other links on the election page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370880)

Comment: I don't *think* I'm seeing a different font (at least in Chrome on my MacBook Pro) - but on the 2021 election pages for the sites linked in the post, the "history" button is currently displayed marginally higher (vertically) on the line than the "link" and "flag" buttons for me. And in the [current Math.SE election page](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/9), the "history" button actually displays slightly lower on the line than the other buttons.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["History" button is not aligned with the other links on the election page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370880/history-button-is-not-aligned-with-the-other-links-on-the-election-page). This issue has been fixed according to the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/379541/513150) to the linked question.