# Nominations "history" button is not aligned with the other links on the election page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, election

I noticed that the "history" button (under each nomination) is positioned slightly higher than the other links/buttons. This can be observed on the current Stack Overflow [election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election/13) <sup>(yes, it's just one pixel but still noticeable)</sup>:

[image: Action links/buttons on current Stack Overflow election]

Here's another screenshot from [Bricks](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=ended):

[image: Action links/buttons on ended Bricks election]

One more thing, the first letters of the words on post action links/buttons were [capitalized recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359477/348196) but they're not capitalized here. They probably should be changed for consistency.

Comment: @Aaron If you're planning on capitalizing the first letters of the links, you might want to consider capitalizing [these ones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07S1X.png) too while you're at it.

Comment: Related: [Inconsistent tooltip capitalisation on question pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323795/284827)

Comment: On the 2021 election pages for the sites linked in the post, the "history" button is currently displayed marginally higher (vertically) on the line than the "link" and "flag" buttons for me. And in the [current Math.SE election page](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/9), the "history" button actually displays slightly lower on the line than the other buttons.

Comment: @V2Blast For me, it's displayed higher in both.

Comment: @JNat sorry, there's still a difference ([example](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election/6?tab=nomination#post-320081)) on various browsers in macOS ...

Comment: Oh, I see — thanks for pointing that out, @Glorfindel! I'd tried repro'ing and failed to, and since the answer was accepted and mentioned if being fixed, I had assumed it had been.

Comment: What's going on with the tag edits? Is this really so hard to know once and for all whether it's fixed or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you everyone for all the helpful information in identify the lingering issue! The position of the "History" button was being thrown off when icons are displayed next to the text links. We have applied styling to vertically center these items so they should all appear in line now.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to have been (partially, see below) fixed at some point in time, both the alignment and the capitalization:

[image]

([here](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/election/2?tab=nomination) is a live election where you can check; [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20220802160102/https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/election/2?tab=nomination) is a Wayback Machine snapshot for posterity)

but not on (some?) other sites, as [this nomination](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election/6?tab=nomination#post-320081) shows:

[image]

'Link' is an HTML anchor and 'History' a button (styled as a link, and apparently some custom site themes react differently to that).

For the record, I'm using Firefox on macOS (latest versions of both) and it's also happening on Safari.

Comment: For me, it looks fine on both election pages (Lifehacks and ELL). So, it might be browser-specific. I'm using Chrome 64-bit on Windows 10.

Comment: It might be a Windows vs. macOS thingy, yes.

Comment: There's an election going on at MathOverflow, if you'd like to check whether it's still happening on macOS for you. :)

Comment: @TheAmplitwist it's looking fine there, but as implied in the answer, it might have something to do with custom site designs.

Comment: Oh! I guess I missed that implication, I thought it might only be OS or browser specific, as discussed in the comments above. Thanks for checking, though!

Comment: @TheAmplitwist yeah, it's confusing, since the original answer (see the revision list) stated it was 100% solved.